# How to use GetProcAddress with JNA?

Tags: java, c++, jna, getprocaddress, jnaerator

First of all, i'm a JNA newbie. I would like to control my motherboard's LED lighting from java code. Asus provides an SDK for this purpose which is written in C (C++?).

Their header file looks simple:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>


typedef void* MbLightControl;
typedef void* GPULightControl;
typedef void* ClaymoreKeyboardLightControl;
typedef void* RogMouseLightControl;


typedef DWORD(WINAPI* EnumerateMbControllerFunc)(MbLightControl handles[], DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetMbModeFunc) (MbLightControl handle, DWORD mode);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetMbColorFunc) (MbLightControl handle, BYTE* color, DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* GetMbColorFunc) (MbLightControl handle, BYTE* color, DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* GetMbLedCountFunc)(MbLightControl handle);

typedef DWORD(WINAPI* EnumerateGPUFunc)(GPULightControl handles[], DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetGPUModeFunc) (GPULightControl handle, DWORD mode);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetGPUColorFunc) (GPULightControl handle, BYTE* color, DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* GetGPULedCountFunc)(GPULightControl handle);

typedef DWORD(WINAPI* CreateClaymoreKeyboardFunc)(ClaymoreKeyboardLightControl* handle);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetClaymoreKeyboardModeFunc) (ClaymoreKeyboardLightControl handle, DWORD mode);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetClaymoreKeyboardColorFunc) (ClaymoreKeyboardLightControl handle, BYTE* color, DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* GetClaymoreKeyboardLedCountFunc)(ClaymoreKeyboardLightControl handle);

typedef DWORD(WINAPI* CreateRogMouseFunc)(RogMouseLightControl* handle);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetRogMouseModeFunc) (RogMouseLightControl handle, DWORD mode);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* SetRogMouseColorFunc) (RogMouseLightControl handle, BYTE* color, DWORD size);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* RogMouseLedCountFunc)(RogMouseLightControl handle);
```

I used JNAerator to get the JNA mappings, and this is the result i got:

```
import com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.runtime.LibraryExtractor;
import com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.runtime.MangledFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback;

public interface Aura extends Library {

    String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = LibraryExtractor.getLibraryPath("AURA_SDK", true, Aura.class);

    NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB = NativeLibrary.getInstance(Aura.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, MangledFunctionMapper.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    Aura INSTANCE = (Aura) Native.loadLibrary(Aura.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, Aura.class, MangledFunctionMapper.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    interface EnumerateMbControllerFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(PointerByReference handles, int size);
    }

    interface SetMbModeFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, int mode);
    }

    interface SetMbColorFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, Pointer color, int size);
    }

    interface GetMbColorFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, Pointer color, int size);
    }

    interface GetMbLedCountFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle);
    }

    interface EnumerateGPUFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(PointerByReference handles, int size);
    }

    interface SetGPUModeFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, int mode);
    }

    interface SetGPUColorFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, Pointer color, int size);
    }

    interface GetGPULedCountFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle);
    }

    interface CreateClaymoreKeyboardFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(PointerByReference handle);
    }

    interface SetClaymoreKeyboardModeFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, int mode);
    }

    interface SetClaymoreKeyboardColorFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, Pointer color, int size);
    }

    interface GetClaymoreKeyboardLedCountFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle);
    }

    interface CreateRogMouseFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(PointerByReference handle);
    }

    interface SetRogMouseModeFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, int mode);
    }

    interface SetRogMouseColorFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle, Pointer color, int size);
    }

    interface RogMouseLedCountFunc extends StdCallCallback {
        int apply(Pointer handle);
    }
}
```

In the example C++ code they use GetProcAddress to obtain the address to the above methods, and that way they can call them:

```
HMODULE hLib = nullptr;

hLib = LoadLibraryA("AURA_SDK.dll");

(FARPROC&)EnumerateMbController = GetProcAddress(hLib, "EnumerateMbController");

DWORD _count = EnumerateMbController(NULL, 0);
```

How do i do the same with JNA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the header files look as they do, but based on the C sample you provided, the function *EnumerateMbController* that resides in the library *AURA_SDK* is called with two parameters - the first one being an array of *MbLightControl* (these are opaque pointers) and the second an that represents the "size".

I would deduce from context:

- The *MbLightControl* array will receive the pointers
- *size* is the size of the array you provide
- the return value of the function will be the number of *MbLightControl* entries really returned

The call with NULL indicates, that it will return the number of MbLightControl instances it would return.

My suggestion for the correct binding:

```
public interface Aura extends StdCallLibrary {

    Aura INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("AURA_SDK", Aura.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public static class MbLightControl extends WinDef.PVOID {}

    public int EnumerateMbController(MbLightControl[] handles, int size);
    public int SetMbMode(MbLightControl handle, int mode);
    public int SetMbColor(MbLightControl handle, byte[] color, int size);
    public int GetMbColor(MbLightControl handle, byte[] color, int size);
    public int GetMbLedCount(MbLightControl handle);
}
```

This loads the dll called *AURA_SDK* and makes five functions accessible. It also mimics the typedef in the header files for *MbLightControl*. The *DWORD*s are bound as java ints to make calling easier, as an *int* in java is always 32 Bit and a *DWORD* on Windows is the same.

I don't know the details of the color codes, but if these are RGB leds, then I assume, that each LED will occupy 3 bytes in the byte array.

It might help to know, that under the hood JNA used *LoadLibraryEx* (the big brother of *LoadLibrary*) and also *GetProcAddress* to load functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll not be able to try itt until next monday. I'll post an update then.